# Cannot Import "wfdb" module after installing it using pip install wfdb

Tags: python, pip, installation

I needed to "wfdb" module for my current project, After installing it in my Jupyter notebook using pip install wfdb it was installed successfully. However, when I tried to import, it showed 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wfdb'
I checked it using pip show  wfdb and the location it returned was 
/home/rashid139/Desktop/django2.x/lib/python3.6/site-packages.
.

I also checked the site-packages directory and wfdb was present there.
['numpy',
 'psycopg2-2.8.4.dist-info',
 'mpl_toolkits',
 'pandas',
 'requests',
 'requests-2.22.0.dist-info',
 'mne-0.20.5.dist-info',
 'sklearn-0.0.dist-info',
 'scikit_learn.libs',
 'docutils-0.15.2.dist-info',
 'pandas-1.0.4.dist-info',
 'matplotlib-3.2.1.dist-info',
 'pytz',
 'matplotlib-3.2.1-py3.6-nspkg.pth',
 'urllib3-1.25.7.dist-info',
 'opencv_python-4.2.0.34.dist-info',
 'rest_framework',
 '**wfdb-3.0.1.dist-info**',
 'pip',
 'matplotlib',
 'sklearn',
 '**wfdb**',
 'scikit_learn-0.23.1.dist-info']
 Please suggest to me where I have problems importing my wfdb module.

Comment: How exactly did you try to import it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. You should open your Conda environment and type:

```
conda install -c conda-forge wfdb
```

Then restart your Jupyter Notebook. It should work.

Comment: I have also followed this procedure but no success, If I import it into t local cmd python shell it is working fine but not on Jupiter notebook